# Frappe installation error "AttributeError: module 'pyparsing' has no attribute 'downcaseTokens'"

Tags: httplib2, frappe

When I install frappe ( version-13 ) on linux

when I run `bench init`

it gives an error

> ERROR: httplib2 0.20.1 has requirement pyparsing<3,>=2.4.2, but you'll have pyparsing 3.0.0 which is incompatible.

though the installation goes through.

After that when a new site is created it gives an error

> AttributeError: module 'pyparsing' has no attribute 'downcaseTokens

which is a deprecated function not available in version 3.0 but available in 2.4.2

How do I get around this issue ? Can I force install an earlier version of pyparsing ?

Regards
Hari

Comment: Fixed in httplib2 0.20.2, released Nov 2, 2021

Answer (score 21):

That python package is using a deprecated function in `pyparsing`.

you can force install any version of a python module as,

```
pip install pyparsing==2.4.2
```

Comment: `pygsheet` also broke for the same reason. Thanks for the quick fix.

Comment: how can I use with  the new version?

Answer (score 2):

well I think I found a Fix for the one's who wants to use the current version of Pyparsing itself. The base package that it creating a problem is httplib2. so in order to rectify you need to update the httplib2 package.

```
pip install httplib2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with importing tf_slim package and got the same error !

$ pip install httplib2

This will resolve the  "AttributeError: module 'pyparsing' has no attribute 'downcaseTokens'" error.